# How to make two div inside a card display side by side

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, angular-material

I'm trying to come out with following card for profile details. But the grid system is not giving me the expected result. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Output:

[image: output]

Expected result:

[image: expected result]

Code:

[image: code]

Comment: There are several things wrong with the way you've asked your question.  Read [ask].

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add your code to this question and not a screen shot of code. If someone is searching for a similar solution, they will not find it, since screen shots are not indexed.

Comment: Alright. I will keep that in mind next  time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how to do it using Grid:

It is very similar the main difference is grid-template-columns, I recommend using Flexbox since this is a 1-dimensional issue which is what Flex was built to solve. Flex and Grid are best used together :D

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  width: 300px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
  column-gap: 25px;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #f4f4f4;
}

.icon img {
  height: 100px;
}

.info label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="icon">
    <img src="https://www.pngall.com/wp-content/uploads/5/Profile-PNG-Clipart.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="info">
    <label>First Name</label>
    <label>Last Name</label>
    <label>Position</label>
    <label>Identification No.</label>
    <label>Email</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, so if i want to add one more set of labels next to the existing label. how do i do that ya? it means i want to have like three columns in one row. one for icon user, one for the labels and one more for the data. all in one card.

Comment: Hello, so you can just add another div with the <label> inside them, as long as the div is within the container it will be put side by side. Link: https://codepen.io/andrewnyrivera/pen/wvqxrjO

Comment: Here is the grid version of it https://codepen.io/andrewnyrivera/pen/wvqxrjO

Comment: Here is the correct codepen for Flex: https://codepen.io/andrewnyrivera/pen/mdMjXMx

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using Display Flex in the parent container also setting the labels to block elements so they go on separate lines.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  gap: 30px;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #f4f4f4;
  width: 300px;
}

.icon img {
  height: 100px;
  
}
.info label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="icon">
    <img src="https://www.pngall.com/wp-content/uploads/5/Profile-PNG-Clipart.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="info">
    <label>First Name</label>
    <label>Last Name</label>
    <label>Position</label>
    <label>Identification No.</label>
    <label>Email</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks ya. working.

Comment: Awesome! Glad I could help!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Do not post two answers to the question. Copy the content of one of them and merge them together. OP is using bootstrap and the parent (`row`) is already a flex parent. While your solution may work, it doesn't get to the core of why it's not working for OP in the first place.

Comment: Okay, thank you for letting me know I will remember next time. :D

Comment: Not next time. You should merge your answers now. It looks like your Grid version is getting more comments, so I would move this one to the other and delete this one. Your answers are likely to get down voted and closed if you don't do this.